# Configuring Roundup with Apache

Tags: python, apache, roundup

I think I just need a bit more guidance than what the documentation
gives, and it's quite hard to find anything relating to Roundup and
Apache specifically.

All i'm trying to do currently is to have Apache display what the
stand-alone server does when running roundup-server
support=C:/Roundup/

Running windows XP with apache 2.2 and python 2.5 roundup 1.4.6

I don't really have any further notes of interest, so **if anyone has already
got this running, could you please show me your configuration** and i'll
see how i go from there :) I don't expect anyone to analyse the 403 forbidden error I get before I'm sure my httpd.conf file is correct first

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

First, requires the following modules enabled:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Then, the following lines are needed to ensure any requests to /issues/ are directed to the **already running** roundup-server thread. Apache doesn't actually deal with the code it just passes it on! As below, i'm only worried about getting one tracker to run currently, let alone all of them as it's running on a server with other modules and I'm really not sure how to make virtual hosts work on my domain.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    # proxy through one tracker
    ProxyPass /issues/ http://localhost:80/issues/
    # proxy through all tracker(*)
    #ProxyPass /roundup/ http://localhost:80/
</IfModule>
```

And that's it :) Just ensure you have roundup-server -p 8080 issues=C:/Roundup/ going on in the background and it should accept requests through Apache.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy to run roundup under Apache if you use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Unfortunately I've since moved away from roundup and no longer have a copy of my wsgi script to show you, but you should be able to figure it out from this [mod_wgi mailing list thead](http://markmail.org/message/y3xnnjnokjbr2rqu#query:roundup%20mod_wsgi+page:1+mid:3kxo57rdfqxqlgxj+state:results).

Comment: @Van Gale Thanks, not quite the answer I was looking for since we're using mod_python. I'll keep it in mind though for when we eventually use the wsgi configuration. Hopefully soon because mod_python is a pain! :)

Comment: @Van Gale: If I might ask, what have you started using since moving away from Roundup? Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew: I have been using redmine (http://www.redmine.org) even though it ended up being a little more painful to install than roundup.  It's just that I needed multiple-project support with clients only having visibility on their projects and integration with git.